# 'Auto' value in binding property 'width'

Tags: wpf, binding, width

Must attach to the property Width, what I'm doing this:

```
     <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Path=TabPanelWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```

-

```
     public float TabPanelWidth
     {
         get {return (float) GetValue (TabPanelWidthProperty);}
         set {SetValue (TabPanelWidthProperty, value);}
     }
     public static readonly DependencyProperty TabPanelWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register ("TabPanelWidth", typeof (float), typeof (BivTabControl), new UIPropertyMetadata (null));
```

But I need a possibility to set not only fixed values, but the values which are expressed in XAML as `Auto`, `0.5*`, and the like.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TabPanelWidth` property must be of type [`GridLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength.aspx). With `GridLength` you can set auto/star size using [`GridUnitType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridunittype.aspx).

In fact, I wonder why binding to a `float` works at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same datatype instead of a `float`, it's called [`GridLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength.aspx).